# Error in declaring component in Angular 16

Tags: angular, components, angular15

I'm learning angular, following the Angular.io tutorial.
I've declared a home component in the angular app, using the provided code:

`ng generate component home --standalone --inline-template --skip-tests`

And the component has the property -> `standalone: true`

Still, whenever I define the component in AppComponent, the statement:

`import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';`

and then as mentioned, the step:

`imports: [ HomeComponent,  ],`

but the imports statement throws out an error.
Also, the changes in module also throw out error.

I've checked out but couldn't find what the actual issue is. Can anybody help me fixing this ?

**Approaches I did:**
I tried defining HomeComponent as standalone: true
Also used the command : `ng g c temp`.
Here it didn't put any error but afterwards when I declare another component, the same issue pops up.
Also, someone suggested me to comment out the imports line in the @Component block, that also didn't work.
Even in the app.module.ts it didn't work.

Since I'm already importing it in modules, I don't get it why do I have to put it again in the AppComponent. But that also didn't work.

Comment: Please share more code, and post the error message too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you **can't** use a standalone component inside a traditional modular component.

#### First way to solve:

Make the complete App to a standalone app. So change your `main.ts` like this:

```
import {bootstrapApplication} from '@angular/platform-browser';
.....
bootstrapApplication(MyAppComponent)
```

`bootstrapApplication` initialize a standalone component without using modules.

#### Second way (better in your case)

You can navigate to your component by using a router. Let's say you initialize your app normal with AppModule.. Init the router

```
routes = [ { path: '', component: MyStandaloneComponent, pathMath: 'full' } ]
```

Then your component will works. And inside your standalone component you can add more standalone components. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#routing-and-lazy-loading) is the official tutorial (which is using this way)